# Replace values from a column of one dataframe by values from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find the solution to this problem, I have two data frames, one is like

```
DF1

faID    uID
1     20909
1     6661
1     1591
1     28065
1     42783
1     3113
1     21647
1     3825
2     134766
2     271168
2     16710
2     4071608
2     2046526
2     5081272
```

and another data frame look like this

```
DF2

uID   user_cent_w
1591    15844
42783   466
21647   1514
29695   13958
94120   3615
83098   128
138776  709
90352   991
115384  8039
74483   128
```

I want to add a new column `user_cent` to `DF1` and the value of that column match the values of `uID` in `DF2` or replace the values of `uID` in `DF1` by the value of  `user_cent_w` in `DF2`, i.e., if `uID` of `DF1` matches the value of `DF2`, i.e., `user_cent_w` then replace `uID` by `user_cent_w` values.

I have tried the solution from

[replace value in dataframe based on another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408339/replace-value-in-dataframe-based-on-another-data-frame)

but this replaces the values of `faID` as well in `DF1`.

My expected output will look like this:

```
faID   user_cent_w
  1      15844
  1      466
  1      1514
  1      13958
  1      3615
  1      128
  1      709
  1      991
  1      8039
  1      128
  1      6489
  1      1781
  2      5735
  2      2072
  2      128
  2      128
  2      2304
  2      9301
  2      1282
```

Comment: Could you show the expected output

Comment: try `merge(df1, df2, by = "uID", all.x = TRUE)`; does this approximate what you wish to achieve?

Comment: yep it works in both merge and the probable solution by @akrun thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 library(dplyr)
 res <- left_join(df1,df2,by="uID")
 res$uID[!is.na(res$user_cent_w)] <- res$user_cent_w[!is.na(res$user_cent_w)]
 res[,1:2]
   res[,1:2]
  #  faID     uID
  #1     1   20909
  #2     1    6661
  #3     1   15844
  #4     1   28065
  #5     1     466
  #6     1    3113
  #7     1    1514
  #8     1    3825
  #9     2  134766
  #10    2  271168
  #11    2   16710
  #12    2 4071608
  #13    2 2046526
  #14    2 5081272
```

Or

```
  left_join(df1, df2, by="uID") %>% 
  mutate(uID=ifelse(is.na(user_cent_w), uID, user_cent_w)) %>%
  select(-user_cent_w)
```

Comment: after a long time realized there is small problem and that is that some of the value of variable(faID) matches the values of (uID) so the code is not replacing that values i.e for example "faID" has a value 2090 and this is also in "uID" . so the code does not replace the value and leaves the uID (which is a number not a value of that user-cent-w.

Comment: @user3841811 Did you updated the dataset and the expected result?

Comment: I think the code is doing well what the problem is that my computer didnot calculate the value for user_cent_w for all of the user(uID)

Comment: yes 2nd code is doing my job the 1st one is just confirming the centrality values

Comment: @user3841811 If it is not the code problem, what do you want me to do?

Answer (score 1):

Although this old question already has an accepted answer, I would like to add two `data.table` solutions for the sake of completeness.

The first one creates a new object

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table and right join on uID
result <- setDT(DF2)[setDT(DF1), on = "uID"][
  # replace uID by user_cent_w where available, remove column
  !is.na(user_cent_w), uID := user_cent_w][, -"user_cent_w"]
result
```

> ```
>         uID faID
>  1:   20909    1
>  2:    6661    1
>  3:   15844    1
>  4:   28065    1
>  5:     466    1
>  6:    3113    1
>  7:    1514    1
>  8:    3825    1
>  9:  134766    2
> 10:  271168    2
> 11:   16710    2
> 12: 4071608    2
> 13: 2046526    2
> 14: 5081272    2
> ```

The second one updates `DF1` *in place* while joining which avoids to copy the object in order to save memory and time:

```
setDT(DF1)[setDT(DF2), on = "uID", uID := ifelse(is.na(user_cent_w), uID, user_cent_w)]
DF1
```

> ```
>     faID     uID
>  1:    1   20909
>  2:    1    6661
>  3:    1   15844
>  4:    1   28065
>  5:    1     466
>  6:    1    3113
>  7:    1    1514
>  8:    1    3825
>  9:    2  134766
> 10:    2  271168
> 11:    2   16710
> 12:    2 4071608
> 13:    2 2046526
> 14:    2 5081272
> ```

#### Data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(faID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), uID = c(20909L, 6661L, 1591L, 28065L, 42783L, 
3113L, 21647L, 3825L, 134766L, 271168L, 16710L, 4071608L, 2046526L, 
5081272L)), .Names = c("faID", "uID"), row.names = c(NA, -14L
), class = "data.frame")

DF2 <- structure(list(uID = c(1591L, 42783L, 21647L, 29695L, 94120L, 
83098L, 138776L, 90352L, 115384L, 74483L), user_cent_w = c(15844L, 
466L, 1514L, 13958L, 3615L, 128L, 709L, 991L, 8039L, 128L)), .Names = c("uID", 
"user_cent_w"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```